# Jquery Iframe/Tab Reload not worked in Mobie devices

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a code to reload a iframeTab content on change of select box.

The works well in all browsers and os in desktop version. But when i am test the same on a mobile device, it doesn't work. The code is

```
$('#'+$('body',parent.document).find('.tab-pane.active').attr('id'),parent.document).attr('src',page);
```

The complete code is

```
function reloadcurrent(pagename,id){ 
    //alert('hello');
    var page='main2.php?page='+ pagename +'&id='+ id;          
     $('#'+$('body',parent.document).find('.tab-pane.active').attr('id'),parent.document).attr('src',page);         
        $('body',parent.document).find('.tab-pane.active').attr('id').contentWindow.location.reload(); 

}
```

So as you can see, i have try Alert which works fine on Mobile devices. But it doesn't load the content in mobile.

Any suggestion will be appropriated.